# Using SSH to tunnel iMessage and Steam

Tags: security, ssh, proxy, firewall, portforwarding

My school is using the firewall to block certain sites and services. I'm in the proccess of writing an application to bypass this. I'm using a dynamic SSH tunnel routed back to 127.0.0.1:8080 as the back-end for this. Everything works except for iMessage and Steam. My research has lead me to believe that this is caused by blocked ports in the firewall. I have attempted to fix this by using Local forwarding but that didn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? If so how could I use SSH port forwarding to make iMessage work behind the firewall.

Comment: I would recommend that you skip your app. Just use the `-D` flag of `ssh`, which makes `ssh` act as a SOCKS proxy, then go configure your system to use that proxy either system-wide or app-by-app.

Comment: Thats what my app does already.